# Text box with clearable values ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, web

I want to implement a textbox like the one used in the tags section when posting a question on StackOverflow...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look to this... it is simple jQuery Tags Input Plugin and easy to use, modify...

http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/